# How to eliminate a space character from a String?

Tags: swift

In my app I have a text field, and when the user presses a button the text he have entered is added to a label. The problem is that if the user add an space at the end, the txt of the label looks bad.

Text field: "Diego "
Label: Great Diego !

Comment: [Like this function does](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.1/type/String/#func-trimmingcharacters-in_)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perform this on your String:

```
let trimmedString = yourstring.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
```

It returns a new string made by removing from both ends of the String characters contained in a given character set, which in this case are whitesspaces and newlines. If you don't want to trim newlines, replace `.whitespaceAndNewLines` with `.whitespace`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String`'s trimming method passing in the characters to be trimmed. One way to do this is:

```
let string = "   something "
string.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
```

Which will remove whitespace and newlines from the beginning and the end of the string.